# sqlite cursor inconsistent behaviour when altering underlying database

Tags: python, sqlite, database-cursor

I have trouble understanding the behaviour of the cursor object of python's sqlite3 module. As far as I understand, the cursor object behaves like an iterator keeping a "view" on the datastructure. Now, I think there are two ways how this behaves:

1) upon execution, the state of the database matching the `SELECT *` statement is kept separated from futures changes

2) upon execution, the state of the database matching the `SELECT *` statement is just a view of the underlying mutable data. I.e. lazy evaluation takes place once the `for ... in cur` line is executed.

But neither is apparently the case, see the script and output below. When executing this script, why is the `UPDATE` command not incorporated into the cursor, but the `INSERT` is? Is it better to just always use `result = list(cur.execute(...))`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite")
con.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
    `id`    INTEGER UNIQUE,
    `name`  TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);""")
con.execute("INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (1, 'smith')")
con.execute("INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (2, 'mia')")
con.commit()
print("in db: (1, smith), (2, mia)")

### Querying the table
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `table`")

### Changing the table
print("altering table: add (3, kim), change (1, smith) to (1, james)")
con.execute("UPDATE `table` SET name='james' where id=1")
con.execute("INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (3, 'kim')")
con.commit()

print()
print("1) expect immutable: (1, smith), (2, mia)")
print("2) expect mutable: (1, james), (2, mia), (3, kim)")
print()
print("But got: ")
for row in cur: print(row)
```

**Output**

```
in db: (1, smith), (2, mia)
altering table: add (3, kim), change (1, smith) to (1, james)

1) expect immutable: (1, smith), (2, mia)
2) expect mutable: (1, james), (2, mia), (3, kim)

But got: 
(1, 'smith')
(2, 'mia')
(3, 'kim')
```

**Platform**

- Ubuntu 18.10 x64
- Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)
- sqlite3.version = '2.6.0'

Comment: I get this: (1, u'james')
(2, u'mia')
(3, u'kim'). I am on Python 2.7 windows 7

Comment: really? Odd, I just checked again with the source code I provided. No avail. What platform are you using? I am on python3.6.7 ubuntu 18.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is the way SQLite works. From [Isolation In SQLite](https://sqlite.org/isolation.html):

> ... But what about changes that occur while the SELECT statement is running? What if a SELECT statement is started and the sqlite3_step() interface steps through roughly half of its output, then some UPDATE statements are run by the application that modify the table that the SELECT statement is reading, then more calls to sqlite3_step() are made to finish out the SELECT statement? Will the later steps of the SELECT statement see the changes made by the UPDATE or not? The answer is that this behavior is undefined... And hence, developers should diligently avoid writing applications that make assumptions about what will occur in that circumstance.

This means that SQLite can provide some isolation between different connections to the same database (beware, only one should write), but you shall not try to modify the database, at least the table(s) being read, between the beginning and the end of a SELECT.

Comment: Tbh. I don't quite understand. I only have one connection, though two different cursors (afaik, connection.execute creates one temporarily). So the savest way to solve this problem is just to use list(..) for everything? What about connection.commit()? Isn't this a synchronization barrier?

Comment: uh, I guess this is the problem I ran into cited in the URL: **No Isolation Between Operations On The Same Database Connection**. So two connections would solve this, instead of using two cursors?

Comment: @JonasB. Yes. It is explicit in the linked page (I only copied what I thought the most relevant part in my answer). If you have two different connections, one is used for a select, and during the select the other one is used for inserts or updates, no modification will be visible in the select.

Comment: I run into locking issues when using two connections. As soon as I call `cur.execute(...)` from one connection, the database is locked until I iterate over the results. I cannot call `con2.commit()` as it times out. I guess using list(...) is the easiest option.
I get the feeling I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: @JonasB. While any number of connections can read from a sqlite database at once, only one can write at a time and nothing can read while that is happening (unless using [WAL mode](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html)).